# Using react.js, I receive no errors, but content doesn't load

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm currently working on a site on freelance, and the client is requesting form verification via react.js. I've never used it before, so I'm trying to learn, and of course, my first goal is to get the content on the page. After some fiddling, and finding my mistakes, I finally received no errors, but the content isn't loading on the page. I'm also using bootstrap. File structure is all correct.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Site Name</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-defualt dc-navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle dc-navbutton collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">
                        Toggle navigation
                    </span>
                    <span class="toggle-bar icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="toggle-bar icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="toggle-bar icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand unfloat" href="#">
                    <img id="logo" src="img/Service2Rev2.png" alt="DockChain">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="dc-navbar collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="fnt-sec nav-pad nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          Settings
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> 
                            About
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="main jumbotron">
            <center class="fnt-secondary">
                <h1>Client's Service</h1>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Learn More</button>
                </a>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="sections">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="center row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>Safe</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non accumsan nulla. Quisque rutrum rutrum condimentum. Aenean lacinia semper egestas. Pellentesque nec tortor eu erat ullamcorper lobortis vitae ut leo. Aliquam ipsum mi, ultrices et posuere id, ornare non quam. Fusce nec augue bibendum, eleifend ipsum viverra, maximus urna. Nullam tincidunt quam id faucibus suscipit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>Secure</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non accumsan nulla. Quisque rutrum rutrum condimentum. Aenean lacinia semper egestas. Pellentesque nec tortor eu erat ullamcorper lobortis vitae ut leo. Aliquam ipsum mi, ultrices et posuere id, ornare non quam. Fusce nec augue bibendum, eleifend ipsum viverra, maximus urna. Nullam tincidunt quam id faucibus suscipit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h2>Verified</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non accumsan nulla. Quisque rutrum rutrum condimentum. Aenean lacinia semper egestas. Pellentesque nec tortor eu erat ullamcorper lobortis vitae ut leo. Aliquam ipsum mi, ultrices et posuere id, ornare non quam. Fusce nec augue bibendum, eleifend ipsum viverra, maximus urna. Nullam tincidunt quam id faucibus suscipit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="sections info-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="some-room row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="center" src="img/Service3.png" alt="flow chart">
            </div>
            <div class="info-text col-md-6">
                <h2>This is how we work</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non accumsan nulla. Quisque rutrum rutrum condimentum. Aenean lacinia semper egestas. Pellentesque nec tortor eu erat ullamcorper lobortis vitae ut leo. Aliquam ipsum mi, ultrices et posuere id, ornare non quam. Fusce nec augue bibendum, eleifend ipsum viverra, maximus urna. Nullam tincidunt quam id faucibus suscipit. Aenean in enim at est porttitor vestibulum eu quis ipsum. Morbi ac tortor tempus, pulvinar nisi at, sodales urna. In facilisis ut diam vel aliquam. Mauris tempor, nulla non hendrerit rhoncus, leo diam dictum elit, nec molestie ex arcu ac erat. Vivamus malesuada libero eget erat bibendum rutrum. Nunc tempus posuere ornare. Sed eleifend, nisl non ultricies pretium, elit diam dictum orci, in aliquet nisi neque luctus lacus. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div id="formDiv">

</div>

<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="main jumbotron">
            <center>
                <h1>Here's another focal point</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non accumsan nulla. Quisque rutrum rutrum condimentum. Aenean lacinia semper egestas. Pellentesque nec tortor eu erat ullamcorper lobortis vitae ut leo. </p>
                <a href="#">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Call to Action</button>
                </a>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fnt-sec pull-left">
            <p><i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> 2015 Client</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fnt-sec pull-right">
            <p>You can have some stuff here too.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- React.js -->
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>

<!-- Form jsx -->
<script src="comp/Form.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">
    var form = React.createElement(Form);
    function run() {
        React.render(form, document.getElementById('formDiv'));
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('onload', run);
    }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's Form.jsx:

```
var Form = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return(
        <div className="container form-border">
        <h2>Enter your info to subscribe.</h2>
        <form>
            <div classNameName="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                <label className="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="Name" />
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group has-warning has-feedback">
                <label className="control-label" for="emailInput">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="Enter email" />
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group has-error has-feedback">
                <label className="control-label" for="passInput">Password</label>
                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="passInput" placeholder="Password" />
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label for="comments">Comments</label>
                <textarea className="form-control" id="commentInput" rows="3" placeholder="Enter comments here"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-6">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="" checked /> Option one
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="" />Option two
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="checkbox disabled">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="" disabled /> Option three (disabled)
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="radio-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked />Option one
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="radio-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" />Option two
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="radio disabled">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3" disabled /> Option three (disabled)
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-6">
                   <div className="form-group">
                   <label for="jobForm">How would you describe yourself?</label>
                    <select name="profession" id="profession" className="form-control">
                        <option value="default">Select an option...</option>
                        <option value="developer">Developer</option>
                        <option value="designer">Designer</option>
                        <option value="director">Director/Manager</option>
                        <option value="joke">Puppet Maker</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label for="useForm">How will you be using this service?</label>
                        <select name="use" id="use" className="form-control" multiple>
                            <option value="personal">Personal</option>
                            <option value="production">Production</option>
                            <option value="corporate">Corporate</option>
                            <option value="joke">With gusto</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="center btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
        );        
  }
});
```

I removed references to the client's service in file names and headers for confidentiality. I can't find why it isn't loading. Can anyone see something I can't?

Comment: "client is requesting form verification via react.js" - that's not really what react does; good luck with the client.

Comment: Try calling run immediately - `DOMContentLoaded` may have fired before the JSX transformer runs your code.

Comment: Well he's requesting that the form verification be done with react.js, because the rest of the site is using it for various reasons.

Comment: I tried that first. Originally I got an error that the id didn't exist, so that's why I added that. Just removed it, still didn't get error, but still didn't get content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the event loader or the call to `createElement`. Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/jsx">

    React.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('formDiv'));

</script>
```

Comment: You, sir, just nailed it. Content's loaded now. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer in case anyone else runs into this too. :) You might also wish to use a less generic classname than `Form` to avoid trouble down the road.

Comment: Accepted it as soon as I could haha. And yeah, my work is just to create the template for it so he can add forms where ever. I'm assuming Form is a keyword?

Comment: It's not a keyword - but there's already an element called `form` - the HTML `<form>` tag. It's generally a bad idea to have two separate entities that differ only by case!